# WCF service not working because of return data type?

Tags: wcf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have created a WCF service with 2 methods :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[SilverlightFaultBehavior]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public IQueryable<object> Service1()
    {
        PivotData pivot = new PivotData();
        IQueryable<object> list = pivot.GeneratePivotData();
        return list;
    }
[OperationContract]
public string Service2()
{
    return "hello";
}
```

}

The Service2 works perfectly fine. However , service1 returns the dreaded 
"the remote server has returned an error : not found"

I believe it has to do with the return type `IQueryable<object>` , but I don't know what I should change to make it work. I tried `List<string>` , `ObservableCollection<object>` and a few others but to no avail.

What should I do the get my data back to the client ?

Thanks

Comment: You have two issues here. The first is IQueryable can't be serialized. Chances are that the underlying type can't be serialised at all. So you want to `ToList()` it. Second issue you have is `System.Object`. WCF probably doesn't know how to serialize the underlying type. Create a concrete (hopefully sealed) class and give it `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes and return a List of that new class.

Comment: I created this class : [DataContract]
    public class BaseClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<string> MyList {get;set;}  
    }  And I still have the error

Comment: umm...what error? Exception Type/Stack trace/Source code.

Comment: the remote server returned an error notfound - CommunicationException - StackTrace :    à System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   à System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   à System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelAsyncRequest.CompleteGetResponse(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: Source code is the same except I return a List<BaseClass> instead of IQueryable<object>

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906953/wcf-communication-exception

Comment: Is it wcf or wcf ria services. Why you tagged as web services.If it is ria I can answer.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz It is ria services, updated the tag accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the question and conversation with Aron.

**I supposed it is a WCF-Ria Services**  If so please retag the question, otherwise you may ignore this answer.

Try the below code.

Beside if you use ria services. you should use , `[Association("FK_assos_name", "field", "field")]` `[Include]` for complex properties and your base class should have at least one `[Key]` attributed field. Such as ID.

```
[OperationContract]
public BaseClass[] ServiceMethod1()
{
    PivotData pivot = new PivotData();
    IQueryable<object> list = pivot.GeneratePivotData();
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

If you still get errors  trace it;In your web.config add the lines below. Then open WcfDetailTrace.svclog with svclog viewer. Red parts will show you what goes wrong.

```
<system.diagnostics> 
<trace autoflush="true"> 
    <listeners> 
    </listeners> 
</trace> 
<sources> 
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" 
            propagateActivity="true"> 
        <listeners> 
            <add name="sdt" 
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                 initializeData= "WcfDetailTrace.svclog" /> 
        </listeners> 
    </source> 
</sources>
```

Comment: Thanks ! The svclog helped a lot. A found one "red part" and the inner exception says : The maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536 '. Change the object graph or increase the quota MaxItemsInObjectGraph.

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget commenting logging part when you publish it.Otherwise .svclog file might grow .